# How to copy specific directory name to a file

Tags: shell

So I have a few directories and I want to copy only the name of the directories that start with 'k' and end with 'g' to a file. How do I do that?

Comment: `printf '%s\n' k*g/ > dirlist.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- k*g(N/) > dirnames.txt
```

Note however that since newline is as valid a character as any in a file name, that means you won't be able to distinguish two files called `k1g`  and `k2g` from one file called `k1g<newline>k2g`.

Instead of printing those dirnames one per line, you could print them NUL-delimited by adding the `-N` option to `print`.

Then, you can post-process the resulting file with things like `dirs=( ${(0)"$(<dirnames.nul-delimited)"} )` or `xargs -r0a dirnames.nul-delimited some-command`.

To also include the name (base name / `t`ail) of the `k*g` files found in subdirectories, you'd do:

```
print -rNC1 -- **/k*g(ND/:t) > dirnames.nul-delimited
```

Note that it could have duplicates if there's both a `a/king` and `.git/king` files for instance.  You could remove duplicates with:

```
() { print -rNC1 -- ${(u)argv} > dirnames.nul-delimited; } **/k*g(ND/:t)
```

An approach to have a file list that is both human readable and post-processable would be to use shell quoting around the file names:

```
print -rC1 -- k*g(N/:q) > dirnames.txt
```

Here using a `zsh`-specific variant of quoting. Or using a portable (in sh-like shells) and more reliable quoting syntax:

```
() { print -rC1 -- ${(qq)argv} > dirnames.txt; } k*g(N/)
```

Or using GNU `ls`:

```
ls -Ud --quoting-style=shell-always -- k*g(N/) > dirnames.txt
```

That list can then later be retrieved with:

```
dirs=( ${(Q)${(zZ[n])"$(<dirnames.txt)"}} )
```

In `zsh`.

Or in both `zsh` or `bash` (or ksh93 if you declared `dirs` as array first):

```
eval "dirs=( $(<dirnames.txt) )"
```

---

If you don't have or can't use `zsh` for some reason, but are on a GNU system, and your filenames are made on valid text in the locale, you could do something approaching with:

- print one per line (assuming file names don't contain newline characters):

  ```
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'k*g' -type d -printf '%f\n' |
    sort > dirnames.txt
  ```
- same NUL-delimited:

  ```
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'k*g' -type d -printf '%f\0' |
    sort -z > dirnames.txt
  ```
- recursive, nul-delimited:

  ```
  find . -name 'k*g' -type d -printf '%f\0' |
    sort -z > dirnames.txt
  ```
- same deduplicated:

  ```
  find . -name 'k*g' -type d -printf '%f\0' |
    LC_ALL=C sort -zu |
    sort -z > dirnames.txt
  ```
- quoted (though sorted in batches)

  ```
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'k*g' -type d -printf '%f\0' |
    xargs -r0 ls -d --quoting-style=shell-always --
  ```
- quoted and properly sorted:

  ```
  find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'k*g' -type d -printf '%f\0' |
    sort -z |
    LC_ALL=C gawk -v 'RS=\0' -v q="'" '
      shquote(s) {
        gsub(q, q "\\" q q, s)
        return q s q
      }
      {print shquote($0)}' |
    xargs -r0 ls -d --quoting-style=shell-always --
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Probably best not to use `ls`, because of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Try:

```
find * -maxdepth 0 -type d -name 'k*g' > filename.txt
```

(Without `-maxdepth 0` it'll also do subfolders of folders. Use `-iname` instead of `-name` if uppercase K and G should also count.)

If there's any possibility that you'll have folders or files that begin with hyphens (but who does that?) you can use this instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'k*g' | sed 's/^\.\///' > filename.txt
```

Notice the switch from `-maxdepth 0` to `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: I suspect this isn't actually better than my answer, although I would encourage folks to use this answer instead because it isn't worse and it might be better. why wouldn't it be better? the core issue is that filenames can contain newlines, and both this answer and mine will dump those newlines into `filename.txt` in a very confusing way that breaks the "one-record-per-line" convention. you could use `-print0`, but now whatever's consuming `filename.txt` has to expect NUL-delimited filenames... it's a nasty problem.

Comment: That fails if there are filenames that start with `-` or are `find` predicates (with potentially severe consequences if one is called `-delete` for instance).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Although part of me feels that anyone who names a file `-delete` deserves whatever happens to them, I have edited the answer with an alternative suggestion for anyone worried about it.

Comment: Another reason not to expand `*` is that it may expand to _too many names_, which would trigger an error when the shell tries to run the `find` command. Note that the `sed` expression could be shortened to `s/..//`, but that it would be better to do that from `find` in a short script called from `-exec`, to avoid issues with names containing newlines.

Comment: @Kusalananda, here `sed 's/^\.\///'` is fine wrt newline as with `-maxdepth 1`,`/` can't occur anywhere else in the file path. `sed 's/..//'` would be a problem though. One could shorten it to `sed 's|./||'` or `sed s:./::` if they felt so inclined.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Ah, with `-maxdepth ` it's safe. So it is. I think I would personally prefer doing it with a parameter substitution in a shell called from `-exec` though (or with a `-printf` format if it was GNU `find`), which would make it future-proof for when the code is reused for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell globbing along with redirection:

```
$ ls -d k*g/ > filename.txt
```

This will break if you have directories whose names contain newline characters. (I *think* it will only pick up directories and not files, but I'm not in front of a computer to check.)

Comment: It *will* only match directories, however `ls` by default will output their *contents* unless passed the `-d` option I think?

Comment: @steeldriver hah, you're totally right! brain fart, fixed!

Comment: It also includes symlinks to directories. Note that it's the shell doing it, not `ls`. `ls` just prints its arguments here.